# dplyr filter function gives wrong data

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have the following dataset: (sample)

```
    Team    Job Question    Answer
1   1        1     2             1
2   1        1     3a            2
3   1        1     3b            2
4   1        1     4a            1
5   1        1     4b            1
```

and I have 21 teams so there are many rows. I am trying filter the rows of the teams which did good in the experiment (with the dplyr package):

```
q10best <- filter(quest,Team==c(2,4,6,10,13,17,21))
```

But it gives me messed up data and with many missing rows.
On the other hand, when I use:

```
q10best <- filter(quest,Team==2 | Team==4 | Team==6 | Team==10 | Team==13 | Team==17 | Team==21)
```

It gives me the right dataset that I want. What is the difference? what am I doing wrong in the first command? 
Thanks

Comment: use `Team %in% c(...)` instead of `Team==c(...)`. `==` means exactly equal, so it's looking for values that are an exact match to your whole character vector. `%in%` means look for value that belong to this vector.

Comment: @scoa if think you should make that an answer

Answer (score 5):

`==` checks if two objects are exactly the same. You are trying to check if one object (each element of `quest$Team`) belongs to a list of value. The proper way to do that is to use `%in%`

```
q10best <- filter(quest,Team %in% c(2,4,6,10,13,17,21))
```